# WPF Combobox with Checkbox checked to different source than content (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I have the following View in my application:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" DisplayMemberPath="Email" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="87,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Checked=""/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The two itemsource Bindings bind to two Lists of the following types:

Country class:

```
public class Country
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Country(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Clients is also another list in my ViewModel

```
public class Client
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Prename { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } = new List<Country>(); 
        public List<AreaType> Areas { get; set; }  = new List<AreaType>();

        public Client() { }
        public Client(string prename, string lastname, string email, List<Country> countires = null, List<AreaType> areas = null)
        {
            Prename = prename;
            Lastname = lastname;
            Email = email;
            Countries = countries;
            Areas = areas;
        }
    }
```

My problem: Im trying to find a way to check the checkboxes in the view if the client has the same country in his list as the checkbox displays.

Example: `View` displays countries from `ViewModel.Countries` 'switzerland', 'germany' and 'austria' and the `ViewModel.SelectedClient.Countries` contrains 'switzerland' and 'austria' then only those two should be checked on the `view`.

Comment: Maybe you can add a boolean to Country "Selected". While creating your clients, set the countries that are available in you country list to selected=true. Then in the xaml you can bind the Selected field to your checkbox.

Comment: @JeroenDop that would work i guess although I dont think its a very nice idea to add a property on a model just to be able to check some checkboxes since this is not the only usage of the country class. Imo that could "corrupt" the model with data that is not relevant to the country itself

Comment: True, you could add a ViewModel ClientCountry with the added property. Add the ClientCountry to the countries list in client.

Comment: @VIP you can also use MultiValueConverter

Comment: A converter can do the trick but then you are not using the MVVM where you change models to change the view. Also when using the property in the model you can set up a 2 way binding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class Country
        {
            public Guid Guid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public bool Selected{get;set;}
            public Country(string name)
            {
                Name = name;
            }
        }

           <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Checked="{Binding Selected}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
```